# Dúvida no "while" com múltiplas condições

Tags: c, while, visual-studio-code

Preciso montar um programa em loop que recebe 4 valores (x0, y0, xf, yf) e, para parar esse loop, é necessário que o usuário digite os 4 valores como 0 (0 0 0 0). Estou usando o comando while para montar esse loop porém, quando o usuário digita apenas um 0, o loop está sendo parado.
Ex: (1 2 0 5). Como posso arrumar o loop e pará-lo apenas quando os 4 valores são 0 simultaneamente? Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
int x0, y0, xf, yf;
char jogada[20];
while(x0 != 0 && y0 != 0 && xf != 0 && yf != 0){
    fgets(jogada, 20, stdin);
    sscanf(jogada, "%d %d %d %d", &x0, &y0, &xf, &yf);
```

Comment: Crie a condição de parada e negue-a.

Comment: *"pará-lo apenas quando os 4 valores são 0 simultaneamente? "* a sua condição já faz isso, ou seja while (enquanto) todos os valores forem diferentes de zero `(x0 != 0 && y0 != 0 && xf != 0 && yf != 0)`. Acontece que nem vai entrar no loop, pq inicalmente os valores podem ser todos zero, basta iniciar um valor diferente de zero antes do loop iniciar, antes do while, por exemplo `x0=1`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Na verdade, se qualquer valor for 0 a expressão inteira será false, parando o laço.

Comment: Nada que um `while ( ! (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0))` não resolva, ou `while (a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0 || d != 0)`, fazendo a distributiva da negação para dentro dos parenteses.

Comment: Consegui dessa forma que você falou, Woss. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -6):

Ao que me parece, você está usando as condições dentro do while, e não no seu escopo. Qualquer looping precisa de um interador, uma variável nesse caso para ponto de partida. Olha como funciona um while.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int contador = 1; //declarando e inicializando a variável de controle
  
  while (contador <= 10) // Testando a condição
  {
    printf("%d ", contador); //Executando um comando dentro do laço
    
    contador++; //atualizando a variável de controle
  }  
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: O seu código até roda, mas a sua resposta está bastante errada. "*Qualquer looping precisa de um interador*", isso não faz o menor sentido.